# JSF 2.2.6 ValueExpression API

Tags: jsf-2.2

Where i can find the ValueExpression API in JSF 2, javax impl?
  Working in a PF project, the value expresoion type was depreciated as eclipse shows this;

```
javax.faces.el.ValueExpression is depreciated.
```

needed in this line;

```
ValueExpression ve = getValueExpression(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is `javax.faces.el.ValueExpression` coming from in your project? The Unified EL is not part of the JSF specification (I think it was introduced along with JSF 1.2 as part of the JSP spec).

The correct full qualified name of the class should be `javax.el.ValueExpression`. This class is available in any servlet container and unless you explicitly use it in your source code you don't have to add it to your project. If you add it, you should make sure the version matches the servlet version of the container you deploy it to (and do not deploy the jar unless you know what you are doing):

- Java EE 5: [EL API 1.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.el%7Cel-api%7C1.0%7Cjar)
- Java EE 6: [EL API 2.2](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.el%7Cel-api%7C2.2%7Cjar)
- Java EE 7: [EL API 3.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.el%7Cjavax.el-api%7C3.0.0%7Cjar)